# Transfer API keys from one organisation to other in GCM

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a very noob question but still need some help urgently. I have an organization in GCM hierarchy where I have some projects using the API keys. Now I want to transfer these projects using these API keys to some other project in a different organization in google cloud (which basically has a lump-sum payment billing)
Can someone help me or guide me regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/migrating-projects-billing#migrating_projects_in_an_organization), it is possible to move projects between organizations. But you need to contact [GCP Support](https://cloud.google.com/support), because they need to confirm certain points with you, then they will remove your project from the original organization and then you can look and select that project and add it to your second organization.